# Receiving 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby' don't know why

Tags: python

```
def read_data(filename):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    newList = []

    columns = ['Resource Name', 'County', 'National Register Date', 'National Register Number', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Georeference']

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        sub = []
        for col in columns:
            index_no = data.columns.get_loc(col)
            sub.append(row[index_no])
        newList.append(sub)
    return newList
def close_by(data, pt, location, lst, otherLst):
    close_locations = []
    long = []
    lati = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        long.append(float(data[i][4]))
        lati.append(float(data[i][5]))
    close_locations = [shapely.geometry.Point(lon, lat) for lon,lat in zip(long, lati)]
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=close_locations, crs={"init":"EPSG:4326"})
    pts = gdf.geometry.unary_union
    ptsArray = np.array(pts)
    point_tree = spatial.KDTree(ptsArray)
    query = point_tree.query_ball_point([location.longitude, location.latitude], 0.5)
    for i in range(len(query)):
        value = query[i]
        lst.append(gdf.iloc[value])
        otherLst.append(gdf.iloc[value][0])
    st.write("List of Nearby National Parks")
    st.write(otherLst)

def county_dict(data):
    counties = dict(data.groupby(['County'])['Resource Name'].count())
    return counties

def bar_chart(counties_dict):
    x = counties_dict.keys()
    y = counties_dict.values()
    plt.bar(x, y)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.xlabel("County")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.title("Frequency of National Parks By County")
    return plt


def display_map(data, otherLst):
    local = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i][0] in otherLst:
            local.append(data[i][4], data[i][5])
    map_df = pd.DataFrame(local, columns=['Resource Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])
    view_state = pdk.ViewState(longitude=map_df['Longitude'].mean(), latitude=map_df['Latitude'].mean(),zoom=10, pitch=0)
    layer = pdk.Layer('ScatterplotLayer', data=map_df, get_position='[Longitude, Latitude]', get_radius = 50, get_color = [0,255,255], pickable=True)
    tool_tip = {'html': 'Resource Name:<br/.{Resource Name}', 'style': {'backgroundColor': 'steelblue', 'color': 'white'}}
    map = pdk.Deck(map_style='mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-b9', initial_view_state=view_state, layers=[layer], tooltip = tool_tip)

    st.pydeck_chart(map)

def main():
    filename = 'National_Register_of_Historic_Places (3).csv'
    data = read_data(filename)
    st.title("Finding NY National Parks Near You")
    streetNum = st.text_input("Enter your number")
    streetName = st.text_input("Enter Your Street Name")
    city = st.text_input("Enter your city")
    lst =[]
    otherLst = []
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Final_Project_Python")
    location = geolocator.geocode(f"{streetNum} {streetName} {city} ")
    pt = Point(location.longitude, location.latitude)
    close_by(data, pt, location, lst, otherLst)
    counties_dict = county_dict(data)
    st.write('Map of Nearby Locations')
    display_map(data, otherLst)
    st.pyplot(bar_chart(data))



main()
```

```
counties = dict(data.groupby(['County'])['Resource Name'].count())
```

I have a dataframe with columns `['Resource Name', 'County', 'National Register Date', 'National Register Number', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Georeference']`. Yet, I receive this error,

> 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby',
> when trying to group by county even though I have specified it as a dictionary.

Comment: You get the error because `data` is _not_  a dataframe like you expect, but a _list_. Python won't usually lie to you in its error messages, so it's best to believe it and try to figure out _why_ `data` is a list when you expect it to be a dataframe. To do that, we're going to need more context than just that one line. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in `read_data()` you create `DataFrame` and list `newList` and you do `return newList` so you return only `list` and later you send this list to function `county_dict()` (and other functions) - so you all time works only with `list`

Answer (score 0):

In `read_data()` you create `DataFrame` and list `newList` and you do `return newList` so you return only list and later you send this list to function `county_dict()` (and other functions) - so you all time work only with list.

You should

```
return data, newList
```

to send both and get it as

```
dataframe, newList = read_data(filename)
```

and later send `dataframe` to `county_dict()` and `newList` to other functions.

But I don't understand why you need this `newList`. Maybe you should use only `dataframe` in all functions.